# can apple enterprise system block somebody from using an app

Tags: ios, iphone, iphone-developer-program

So given the scenario, a company distribute an app to all of its employees via the apple enterprise program. Then let's say person y decides to leave the company. Can the company remove person y from using the app? I'm trying to decide if a login system is necessary or not.

Thanks
please ignore below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
  <!-- Array der Downloads. -->
  <key>items</key>
  <array>
   <dict>
    <!-- Array der zu ladenden Ressourcen -->
     <key>assets</key>
      <array>
       <!-- Softwarepaket: die zu installierende ipa-Datei. -->
        <dict>
         <!-- Pflicht: die Art der Ressource. -->
          <key>kind</key>
          <string>software-package</string>
          <!-- Pflicht: die URL der zu ladenden Datei. -->
          <key>url</key>
          <string>%url%</string>
        </dict>
      </array><key>metadata</key>
      <dict>
       <!-- Pflicht -->
       <key>bundle-identifier</key>
       <string>%bundleIdentifier%</string>
       <key>bundle-version</key>
       <string>%bundleVersion%</string>
       <!-- Pflicht: die Art des Downloads. -->
       <key>kind</key>
       <string>software</string>
       <!-- Pflicht: der beim Download anzuzeigende Titel. -->
       <key>title</key>
       <string>%title%</string>
      </dict>
    </dict>
  </array>
</dict>
```